# Initialize spring bean field after application started

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

My spring boot application needs to load some data to a bean's field from database as cache when application started, what I did is as code blow

```java
@Component
public class FooCache {

  private FooRepository repository;
  private static List<Foo> foos;

  public FooCache(FooRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    foos = repository.findAll();
  }
}
```

The questions are

- Is it guaranteed that the database connection pool is properly initialized before the `onApplicationEvent` is called?
- Is it guaranteed that the `foos` initialized before the application handle requests from users?
- Is this a proper manner to set application cache, any other best practices to achieve this? (I mean caching data from database on application initialized specifically)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with connection DataBase but I used  @Bean ApplicationRunner init to initialize my object in the running of my application but you can test it maybe can help you

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class CarServiceApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CarServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
ApplicationRunner init(CarRepository repository) {
    return args -> {
        Stream.of("Ferrari", "Jaguar", "Porsche", "Lamborghini", "Bugatti",
                "AMC Gremlin", "Triumph Stag", "Ford Pinto", "Yugo GV").forEach(name -> {
            repository.save(new Car(name));
        });
        repository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    };
}
```

}

Comment: The second guarantee is also important to me

Comment: this method can help you to init your object in the start of your application